# how can I make it so that radio button is cleared when textbox is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

am just wondering is there a way for me to make it so that when a textbox is clicked it will clear the radio button. also to note I have group the radio buttons. here is the code obviously this is not all of the code but it only this part i need help with thanks.

here's an image of the program

[image]

```
if (newMaterialother.Length < 1)                      
throw new Exception("must be more than 1 character long ");                
  if (rbnProcelain.IsChecked == false)                    
 newMaterialother = "Procelain";                
 if (rbnChina.IsChecked == false)                    
 newMaterialother = "Chain";                
 if (rbnClay.IsChecked == false)                    
 newMaterialother = "Clay";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the group box is grpMaterialOptions and the text box is txtOther, then if you are not going to be adding more radio buttons, you can just set the 'Checked' property on all of the radio buttons to 'false' when clicking the text box.

If we also assume the form is called Form1, then either add a Click event against txtOther from within the Form's constructor (or just from in the designer):

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtOther.Click += txtOther_Click;
    }
```

Then, un-check each of the radio buttons within the click event:

```
        private void txtOther_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
    }
```

Alternatively, if you're planning on adding more radio buttons to the panel or you're planning on just having a large number of radio buttons, you might try something more verbose; the following will only need implemented once and will work for however many radio buttons you want to add in:

```
        private void txtOther_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in grpMaterialOptions.Controls)
        {
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                (c as RadioButton).Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```